# Retrieving BLOB image from database using autocomplete selection

Tags: javascript, php, database, image, xhtml

I'm trying to display a blob image stored in a database, I'm not getting any errors but the image isn't displaying, I'm just getting the default "no image" icon. Here's my code:

```
<script>
  function showEmpimg(str) {
    var xhttp;
    if (str == "") {
      document.getElementById("user-id").innerHTML = "";
      return;
    }
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("face").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST", "getimage.php?q="+str, true);
    xhttp.send();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="face" class="face"> 
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user-id" placeholder="ID" name="emp_id" onchange="showEmpimg(this.value)" required maxlength="6" />
```

And the php file:

```
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","test1","dar");
$sql = "SELECT emp_img FROM employees WHERE emp_id LIKE 'q'";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['emp_img'] ).'"/>';

?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the content of `$result['emp_img']`?

Comment: It should me a BLOB .jpg file. From the database. When inspecting the code after executing, the img src shows "data:image/jpeg;base64," but not the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","test1","dar");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_id=" . intval($_GET['q']);
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);

 //var_dump($result);
echo '<img class="face" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['emp_img'] ).'"/>';
```